# expo Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: react-native, expo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I worked on a project with expo/react-native and everything work fine in ios simulator but I'm getting this error on android emulator(Genymotion) and on my iPhone device.

I attached the screenshot.

[android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8fHl.png)

Answer (score 4):

Every `promise` must have an associated `catch` for error handling purposes to remove the warning.

If `.then()` was used, then you need to have a `.catch()` linked to it.

If `try {}` was used, then you need to have a `catch {}` linked to it.